# GraphMethodException - Unsupported get request at

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ssl

I have two Debian-systems. With both I access the Facebook-API via Perl(Facebook::Graph).
On the first system this works perfectly, on the other system I ran into following problem.

> Could not execute request (https://graph.facebook.com): GraphMethodException - Unsupported get request at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Facebook/Graph/Response.pm line 40

Response.pm:

```
[...]
has response => (
    is      => 'rw',
    isa     => 'HTTP::Response',
    required=> 1,
);
[...]
ouch $response->code, 'Could not execute request ('.$response->request->uri->as_string.'): '.$message, $response->request->uri->as_string;
[...]
```

I know it has something to do with my ssl-libs, but I cannot figure out where the problem is. I reinstalled multiple times the IO:Socket:SSL and SSLeay.

Every help is welcome,
enzo

Comment: What are you trying to access and are you using a valid access token to access that information from both places?

Comment: Check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644513/user-opted-out-of-platform-can-post-and-is-viewable-but-not-via-the-graph-api

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps, but came on here looking for help with 'graphMethodException' when trying to access this page: http://graph.facebook.com/doodleembroidery (which works fine now).

Have just tracked it down to the page's country permissions. She didn't realise she had set restrictions when she created the page, now she's removed them the link works fine!